# How Would i go about changing entire <li> via javascript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if theres a method to changing a `<li>` id using a similar method to below.

```
document.getElementById('moderator_viewer_container').innerHTML = "<li id="moderator_viewer_container" style="">

<h4 class="drag_handle drag_handle1">

    Moderator

</h4>
<ul id="moderator_viewer_list" class="viewer_list">
    <li id="chat_user_cyrez" class="nick">
        <a id="chat_user_cyrez-link" class="" href="#">

            cyrez

        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="chat_user_imonicaonline" class="nick">
        <a id="chat_user_imonicaonline-link" class="" href="#">

            imonicaonline

        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

";

so in a sense what i am basically saying is i want to remove that id and replace it with a full edit via html within the javascript

Answer (score 5):

Definitely exists! And here it is:

```
document.getElementById('selected_div').id = 'new-id';
```

Just select your element by old `id` and set a new one. And keep in mind that you can't select it any more with the old `id`.

Comment: While the code seems self explanatory, please just add a few comments to explain to OP what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

... or

```
document.getElementById("selected_div").outerHTML = "<div id="new_id"></div>";
```

which replaces selected `div` and all it's child elements with new HTML content

Answer (score 0):

The DOM api allows you to modify attributes of html elements. After you obtain an html element, you can either access the properties in the following ways:

```
element.property = "foobar";
```

or

```
element.setAttribute("property", "foobar");
```

In your case, you can do

```
element.setAttribute("id", 5);
```

There are also cross-browser issues you should be aware of when dealing with html attributes. See [here](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#attributes).